# C++ - Ordered ArrayList

Tags: c++, arraylist, push

I have an ordered arrayList.  Where elements are to be ordered in 1,2,3,4,5,6.
At the moment the push function is not working.  It will insert an element, but there is a problem which i cannot figure out.  The push will work once you insert an incremented number... So like 1,2,3,4,5  but will not work once i insert like this 5,2,4,3,2,1.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

**Initialisation**

```
template <class Datatype>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class: OrderedArray.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OrderedArray
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Member Variables.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    Datatype* m_array;
    int size;
    int g_size;
    int num_elements;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Name:            Print Function:
    //  Description:     To print out all elemenst in the Array.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i< size;i++)
        {
            cout << "Position: " <<m_array[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Name:           Resize Function:
    //  Description:    To resize the Array.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Resize(int p_size)//resizes the array to the size of p_size
    {
        if(p_size < 0)//checks if new size is less than 0
        {
            cout << "ERROR! Size of an array can not be less than 0!" << endl;
        }
        else//else its ok to continue
        {
            Datatype* newArray = new Datatype[p_size];//creates a pointer newArray that points at a new array
            if(newArray == 0)
                return;

            int min;

            if(p_size < m_size)//checks the if the new array is smaller than the old one
                min = p_size;
            else//else its going to be bigger
                min = m_size;

            int index;
            int temp = num_elements;//puts num_elements into a temporary variable called temp
            num_elements = 0;//num_elements is set to 0
            for(index = 0; index < min; index++)
            {
                newArray[index] = m_array[index];//places everything from the old array into the new array that will fit.
                if(num_elements < temp)//if the num_elements is less than temp(the original num_elements)
                {
                    num_elements++;//increment num_elements. This will keep incrementing to create the new num_elements based the number of elements cut off in the resize
                }
            }
            m_size = p_size;//sets the old size to be equal to the new size

            if(m_array != 0)
                delete[] m_array;//deletes the old array
            m_array = newArray;//makes m_array point at the new array
            newArray = 0;//makes newArray a null pointer
        }
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name:             Push
// Description:      
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void push(Datatype p_item)
{
    if(num_elements == size)//checks if the array is full and needs to be resized
    {
        Resize(size + g_size);//calls the resize function
    }

    int pos = num_elements;
    for(int x=0;x<num_elements;x++)
    {
        if(p_item < m_array[x])
        pos=x;
        break;
    }

    //loops through the array from high to low moving all values to the right
    //to make space for the passed in value until it gets to the right place
    for(int index = num_elements; index >= pos; index--)
    {
        m_array[index] = m_array[index-1];//moves the values to the right
    }
        m_array[pos] = p_item;//the passed in value is positioned into its ordered position
        num_elements++;

    cout<< "Num Elements " << num_elements;
    cout<< "Size " <<size;
}
```

Comment: A storage Container :S

Comment: Where is the `Push` method and why don't you use a `std::vector` instead of C arrays ?

Comment: And you have two `void Resize(int p_size)` methods but zero push functions shown?

Comment: what is meant by `works` and `does not work`?  what is your expected output and what is your actual output

Comment: Try posting code that exhibits the problem and we *may* be able to help.

Comment: Sorry one of the two resize function was supposed to be a push... Il edit it in now :)

Comment: Just a question, what is the point of this?  I know ArrayLists in Java and C# are similar to ```std::vector``` and it looks like it does similar things, like resizing an array to fit.  Is there a reason not to use ```std::vector```?

Comment: Well, Im expecting the user to enter in integers. The user provides integers and the push function is called to add them in an order.  The order being standard numeric... 1,2,3,4,5,10,21,35,60 etc...

Comment: This may also be interesting for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3217/An-STL-compliant-sorted-vector

Comment: @TravisPessetto,  Yes making an arrayList in this way enables me to create my own functions and have more control over the container.

Comment: Becca, I'd recommend you either sub-class `std::vector`, or just have it contained within your own class, and manipulate that as your "backing storage" rather than completely rolling your own.  It will probably get you where you want to go faster, as you can just `push_back()` and then `sort` every time if you want to.

Comment: @Becca again, what happens when you input in the way that causes the error?

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going.  However, in my schooling they point out trying to implement your own code can cause quite a bit of problems and bugs that have been worked out in the standard  libraries. It is also recommended that one uses the standard libraries when possible.  In your case you could sort the vector, if you were to use it with the ```std::sort``` algorithm.  The compiler is also able to optimize the standard libraries so it will most likely go faster than your own implemented code.  But, if you really do need quite a bit of control to the code, then I guess I could see why.

Comment: I don't suppose this class has a constructor, and perhaps a few **public** methods ?

Comment: @SamIam sorry. Basically, if i entered 8,5,7,6,3,2 in that order i would get 5,-33667788,2,-65765365,-65765365.  Whereas if i enter 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order the output will be 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: Sounds like you are going out of the vectors memory and getting garbage somehow.  My guess is that since the original is in order it does not go out of the array's bounds.   While, when you have to sort it is going out of the array's bounds.

Comment: While it's at least theoretically true that implementing your own container *can* give you extra control -- but this should be done when you *need* to, not just because you can. What are you trying to accomplish that an `std::multiset` doesn't provide?

Comment: m_size is also not defined as a member is is referenced in the code (which still contains no constructor, nor any public methods). I concur with most everyone here: that wheel is already perfectly round and very buffed, and its name is `std::vector<>`. Between that and its methods, you would likely not be surprised to see how much of this literally disappears.

Comment: @Becca, if you still insist on implementing your own code I would suggest looking into ```std::sort()```, which looks like it works on arrays.  It will not go out of bounds and is intelligent so it will use the fastest sort for your dataset.  It will also not go out of the bounds of the array.  If you are using the c++ 11 standard I believe you can use ```std::begin()``` and ```std::end()``` on the array too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the beginning of the problem:

```
for(int x=0;x<num_elements;x++)
{
    if(p_item < m_array[x])
        pos=x;
}
```

your `pos` will always always be at the end of the array that way(assuming the array is properly sorted up to that point).  add a `break` statement to let your loop know when it should stop assigning greater and greater values to `pos`

```
for(int x=0;x<num_elements;x++)
{
    if(p_item < m_array[x])
    {
        pos=x;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

your code has some other issues too, for instance

```
for(int index = num_elements; index > pos; index--)
{
    m_array[index] = m_array[index+1];//moves the values to the right
}
```

actually moves the values left.  change the assignment to

```
for(int index = num_elements; index > pos; index--)
{
    m_array[index] = m_array[index-1];//moves the values to the right
}
```

Comment: There must be a problem with the linear search.  Now the values are entering... but outputting unordered,

Comment: @Becca slow down a bit.  Did you make  both of these changes?  and if you did, what is your output now?

Comment: @Becca  did you make the second change.  did you change `m_array[index] = m_array[index+1]` to `m_array[index] = m_array[index-1]`

Comment: @Becca and what does your searching loop look like now?  can you copy/paste it into your question?

Comment: @Becca you need to add the brackets, the `{` and `}` after your if statement.  If you don't have those, your `if` statement will only contain the first line after it.  As your code is right now it will break at the first iteration of the loop, and `pos` will be either `0` or `num_elements`

Comment: This `break` is not needed here at all. It now stops after finding first element that is less than the one being inserted. This is wrong

Comment: @SamIam Yep that worked.  Thanks very much you were so helpful. :)

Comment: @aleguna  actually it stops after finding the first element that **the one being inserted is less than** or in other words, that is greater than the one being inserted.  without the break, it will continue going and insert the element to the right of any element that's larger than it.  This causes the `sorting` to not only be wrong, but different depending on the order in which you enter the elements.